# Toggle true and false

Tags: javascript, toggle

I would like to know how I can toggle this `true` into `false` and vise versa:

```
function step1(enabled, withDialog) {
  if (enabled != undefined && !enabled)
    return;

  var dialogMode = (withDialog ? DialogModes.ALL : DialogModes.NO);
  var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var ref1 = new ActionReference();
  ref1.putEnumerated(cTID('Chnl'), cTID('Chnl'), cTID('Msk '));
  desc1.putReference(cTID('null'), ref1);
  desc1.putBoolean(cTID('MkVs'), true);
  executeAction(cTID('slct'), desc1, dialogMode);

};

if (a == false) {
  !a = true;
} else if (a == true) {
  !a = false;
}
```

Comment: Toggle what? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I dont know why description came out like that, but I hope you can make out, I know very little about coding, but I have found some possible fixes, just dont know how to apply it in my code

Comment: yeah sorry, ok so this part of the code desc1.putBoolean(cTID('MkVs'), true); i would like to change this true to false when I click the button, a toggle

Comment: I found this but dont know why it does not work for me, I know Im doing it wrong though lol           
    if (a == false) {
      a = true;
    } else if (a == true) {
      a = false;
    }

Comment: So you want the last argument to have alternate `true` and `false` value?

Comment: yes so when I click the button, it checks if it is true or false then it toggles it to true if it is already false and visa versa

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which variable you want to toggle in your code, but taking your comment:

```
if(a == false) { a = true; } else if (a == true) { a = false; }
```

You can change it to:

```
a = !a;
```

Comment: desc1.putBoolean(cTID('MkVs'), true); this code I want to toggle

Comment: I edited the code above to make you see what I used and photoshop crashed

Comment: You mean you want to toggle the value of `cTID('MkVs')`? Well, you're using `putBoolean()` to get the Boolean value, so how do you get the value? Do you use `getBoolean()`?